# Django: Save several entries at once in database

Tags: python, django

I tried to avoid writing `new_order['key']= value` all the time and my solution was the one attached. It doesn't work. Can you help me how to fix it?

```
new_order = self.order.save(commit=False)
new_order = {
    'total_gross': self.order_items_dict['total_gross'],
    'total_tax': self.order_items_dict['total_tax'],
    'total_net': self.order_items_dict['total_net'],
    'event': self.order_items_dict['event'],
    'order_reference': order_reference,
    'status': OrderStatus.PAID,
    'access_key': get_random_string(length=10),
    'application_fee': self.order_items_dict['application_fee'],
    'charge_id': charge.id,
    'livemode': charge.livemode,
    'balance_transaction': charge.balance_transaction
}
new_order.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a lot of entries at once, you want Django's `bulk_create`:

```
>>> Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
... ])
```

Your new_order is a dictionary, though. You probably want to do something more like the above example

```
new_order = Order(tax=foo, event=bar)
new_order.save()
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Ah awesome. First time I hear about that. Great tip!